# What is Windows Registry?

Tags: registry

So, I was researching The registry yesterday in conjunction to learning about powershell, I am being led to believe the following fact: The registry is like a memory card for your settings, Your program settings (just about any program) are stored into the registry, and you can CREATE new records that will basically persist the settings of your home made softward, is this correct or have i mistaken

Comment: No, actually I learned how to google things when it first became available and I learned exactly how easy it is to search, especially when looking for readily available information. It saves me lots of time, and I don't end up wasting time of others by asking them things I already know. :-) It's excellent now, because we have both Google and Bing to use to search first. :-) Let me check... Yep, the link I found and posted in my last comment still works.

Comment: @KenWhite I hope to be a google master like you one day, then i will use my google skills to figure out what that bing thing you mentioned is, Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The registry is basically a tree-style database for settings, much the same as a file system is for files.  It's no accident that registry key names look a lot like file paths; the same mechanisms play a role in both.

Windows systems use the registry for just about everything at one time or another.  Nearly every system setting has a place in there.  For example, when you you double-click a `.txt` file, the registry is what tells it "use Notepad to view this type of file".

And yes, you could store your own values in the registry, and many apps do just that.  What the settings do, and whether they'll be per-user settings or machine-wide, depends on where you put them.  There are specific keys reserved for application settings, and if you want to store values without causing wackiness on your user's machine, you'll stick to those locations.